# Is this the right formula to use implied volatility to gauge probability of a stock being within a certain range?

Tags: stocks, options, day-trading, implied-volatility

I read online somewhere, and I can't find it now, that to find the probability of a stock hitting a certain price within a certain time frame, we can use Implied Volatility:

```
X = StockPrice * IV * SQRT(DaysTillExpire / 365)
```

`X` would then be 1 standard deviation (or a +/- 34% probability)

So first, is this accurate and second, how does this work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on quant.stackexchange.com

Comment: To give a hint, though, recognize that implied vol is an annualized standard deviation of returns, and look up formulas for z-scores.

Comment: @DStanley it would likely be perceived as being to basic for the quant page so I htink it actually probably does belong here.

Comment: @MD-Tech I disagree, but in any case it's already been migrated and marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open.  It is about investing in the stock market.  Just because it might be on topic on a different site does not necessarily automatically make it off-topic here.  See [this meta question](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2285/10997).

Answer (score 2):

To get the probability of hitting a target price you need a little more math and an assumption about the expected return of your stock.  First let's examine the parts of this expression.

- **IV** is the implied volatility of the option.  That means it's the volatility of the underlying that is associated with the observed option price.  As a practical matter, volatility is the standard deviation of returns, expressed in annualized terms.  So if the monthly standard deviation is Y, then Y*SQRT(12) is the volatility.
- From the above you can see that **IV*SQRT(DaysToExpire/356)** de-annualizes the volatility to get back to a standard deviation.  So you get an estimate of the expected standard deviation of the return between now and expiration.
- If you multiply this by the stock price, then you get what you have called X, which is the standard deviation of the **dollars gained or lost** between now and expiration.  Denote the price change by A (so that the standard deviation of A is X).

Note that we seek the expression for the probability of hitting a target level, Q, so mathematically we want

1 - Pr( A < Q - StockPrice)

We do 1 minus the probability of being below this threshold because cumulative distribution functions always find the probability of being BELOW a threshold, not above.

If you are using excel and assuming a mean of zero for returns, the probability of hitting or exceeding Q at expiration, then, is

```
1 - NORM.DIST(Q, StockPrice, X, TRUE)
```

That's your answer for the probability of exceeding Q.

Accuracy is in the eye of the beholder.  You'd have to specify a criterion by which to judge it to know the answer.  I'm sure more sophisticated methods exist that are more unbiased and have less error, but I think it's a fine first approximation.